# Extract a column from a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables

I put the output from a command in a variable in PowerShell. Its content looks like this:

```
 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
```

I would like to extract any of the columns and put that in a new variable. I've found ways to that with text files but not with variables.
Thanks for your suggestions!

BC

Comment: So that is `$Something`, right?  Care to share the output of `$Something.GetType()`? If you want to manipulate content, the type of content matters! I'm guessing it's a string, in which case I would start with `$Something -split '\s+'`...

Comment: I get as BaseType "System.Object". Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: "I put the output from a command in a variable in PowerShell..."  ***How?*** What is the variable?

Comment: Please edit your question, adding the code you use for variable cration/assignment as well as the output from a sample variable piped to `Get-Member`, i.e. `$CmdOutput | gm`.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to extract any of the columns and put that in a new variable.

The simplest solution is to extract *all* whitespace-separated tokens from your variable value and store them in an *array*, using the unary form of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator; you can then use indexing to retrieve a token of interest, such as `[0]` to get the first one:

```
$var = '5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -'

# Split the string into tokens by any run of whitespace
# (ignoring leading and trailing whitespace, which aren't present here).
$tokens = -split $var

# Extract the 2nd token, for instance.
# To assign it to a separate variable, use something like:
#   $secondToken = $tokens[1]
$tokens[1] # -> 'Reallocated_Sector_Ct'
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks! PowerShell is a peculiar language.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BartConinckx. PowerShell is certainly unusual, but offers a lot of high-level abstractions that, when embraced, can really boost productivity - but there's a learning cost.